# How to Find a substring in a srting and if true insert text inbetween in PHP?

Tags: php, string

I want to search for a specific substring in given string and if found I want to simply insert some text in between in these strings in PHP.

I have used strpos

```
$text = "Something wordpress"
if(strpos($text,'wordpress',true) !== FALSE)
{
  //Insert <br/> text
}
```

but dont know how to insert text in between in string.

Example output

```
Something <br/> Wordpress
```

Comment: **in between** of what? Provide some example.

Comment: Inbetween Something and wordpress as shown in code above. Like "Something <br/> wordpress"

Comment: You mean to say in this case it is blank space, right?

Comment: I just want to insert a line break if that string contain "wordpress"

Answer (score 1):

```
$text = "Something wordpress";
if(strpos($text,'wordpress') !== false)
{
  str_replace('wodrpress', ' your text ' . 'wordpress', $text);
}
```

Comment: With your permission, can i edit your answer?? Small mistake only.

Answer (score 1):

```
$text = "Something wordpress";
if(strpos($text,'wordpress',true) !== FALSE)
{
    $pos = strpos($text,'wordpress',true);
    $text = substr($text, 0, $pos) . "new text " . substr($text, $pos);
}
echo $text;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$text = "Something wordpress";
if(strpos($text,'wordpress') !== false)
{
 str_replace('wordpress', '<br>wordpress', $text);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do

```
echo str_replace('wordpress', '<br>wordpress', 'Something wordpress');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using "str_replace" (http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).

For example:

```
            $text  = "Something wordpress";
            $searchText = "wordpress";
            $replaceText = "different text";

            $newPhrase = str_replace($healthy, $replaceText, $text);
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why no one mention `substr_replace` for insert..

```
$text = "Something wordpress";
$pos = strpos($text,'wordpress');
if($pos !== FALSE)
{
    $text = substr_replace($text, "<br>", $pos, 0);
}
var_dump($text); // "Something <br>wordpress"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a preg_match. This `preg_match` will search for 'wordpress' and replace it with '
wordpress'.

```
$search = 'wordpress';
$string = preg_replace('/' . preg_quote($search, '/') . '/', '<br />$0', $string);
```

However effective, my method makes no difference with the other answers whatsoever. It is simply a string replace action.